# Linq deferred operations

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I mostly understand deferred execution, but I have a question about a particular case:

Given a code fragment such as

```
                        var resultsOfInterest = from r in ...
                                                select r;
                        foreach (var x in resultsOfInterest)
                        {
                            //do something with x
                        }
```

how many times is the query *resultsOfInterest*  executed? Once when setting up the foreach loop, or once for every element 'x'? Would it be more efficient with

```
                        foreach (var x in resultsOfInterest.ToArray())
                        {
                            //do something with x
                        }
```

?

TIA

Comment: Look at what it's compiled to. A `foreach` becomes a lot more than the simple branch-and-jump that, say, a `for` does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both cases, it only runs once.

In the first example, (if this is a Linq-to-Objects query), it runs just long enough to get the next `x` on each iteration. In the second example, it has to evaluates the entire result set at once and stores it to an array.

So, suppose this is an expensive query and it takes 1 second to get each item, and there are 20 items in the list, both queries will take about 20 seconds to process all items. However, the first one will be blocked for 1 second on each iteration while it gets the next item, but the second will be blocked for 20 seconds before the start of the loop, then loops through all the items in the array fairly quickly.

Neither is more efficient in when it comes to actually evaluating the query. In general, however, you should be avoid unnecessary calls to `ToArray` or `ToList`, since in addition to evaluating the query, it must allocate an array for the results (`List<T>` stores its items in an internal array). For a list of 20 items, this doesn't mean much, but when you have several thousand items, this can cause some noticeable slow-down. Of course, this doesn't mean that `ToArray` is *always* bad. If you had 5 `foreach`-loops in the previous example, storing the results in an array and looping through the array rather than re-evaluating the query each time would actually speed up the code by about 80 seconds

Answer (score 5):

It will be executed once, jut before loop, when `GetEnumerator()` method will be executed over query variable. Here is how *foreach* loop looks like:

```
var enumerator = resultsOfInterest.GetEnumerator(); // query executed here

while(enumerator.MoveNext()) // iterating over results of query execution
{
   var x = enumerator.Current;
   // do something with x
}
```

Second sample will not be more efficient, it simply stores results of query execution in array, and then calls array iterator:

```
var enumerator = resultsOfInterest.ToArray().GetEnumerator();
// loop stays same
```

Comment: Except for certain queries (GroupBy etc.), LINQ executes on-demand _per item_, not prior to the loop at `GetEnumerator`. Also, `foreach` has a `using` statement for the enumerator.

Comment: @CoryNelson I removed *using* for simplicity, but yes, it should be there (actually *using* is also syntax sugar for try-catch-Dispose). And yes, you are correct - for operators which do not support deferred execution, query will be executed immediately. However in this case we have deferred execution.

Comment: So I guess that if I were to use the query in two subsequent statements, it would then be evaluated twice and a ToArray() subscript to the query would be more efficient?

Answer (score 0):

In both cases, the *query* is only executed once, but in the second case there are two *enumerations*.

Assuming 1000 items:

Case 1:

1. Execute the `select` clause, assign result to `x`.
2. Goto 1, repeat 1000 times.

Case 2:

1. Create array.
2. Execute the `select` clause, assign result to the array.
3. Goto 2, repeat 1000 times.
4. Access an element from the array, assign it to `x`.
5. Goto 4, repeat 1000 times.

So generally creating an array is not desirable at all. But if you need to enumerate the same items multiple times yourself, and array access is faster than your `select`, then of course it would be more efficient to create the array.